# VS C++ not releasing memory after bad_alloc exception

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, out-of-memory

Using Visual Studio 2013 C++, I have a program that in some situation can run out of memory. I catch the bad_alloc exception and delete the allocated memory. When after this memory is allocated again a bad_alloc exception is thrown, as if no memory was release at all.

The first exception was captured and the deletes were executed. The second exception is thrown in new.cpp by a statement with as comment "report no memory"

In the example here the exception will be thrown when executing the last statement in main():

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

struct Object {
    char Data[10000];
};

vector<Object*> OutOfMem;

void GetOutOfMemory()
try{
    while( true ){
        Object *O{ new Object };
        O->Data[0] = '#';
        OutOfMem.push_back( O );
    }
}
catch( const std::bad_alloc &Ex ){
    for( auto o: OutOfMem )
        delete o;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GetOutOfMemory();

    Object *O{ new Object };
    OutOfMem.push_back( O );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried also emptying the OutOfMem vector?

Comment: You're right, the vector still holds the pointer so memory management will not release it yet. Adding `OutOfMem.clear()` effectively releases it.

Comment: When you get a `bad_alloc` exception, you are pretty much hosed. There is little point in trying to catch it. Your program cannot hope to recover.

Comment: To complete the answer (it turns out that my real program did clear the vectors) there is a circular data structure, object A pointing to object B pointing to... pointing to A. The memory manager will free none of the objects. A typical error but easlily overlooked...

Comment: @ Cody Gray: It does make sense, the user can launch a normal search and a "deep search", it is the deep search that can occasionaly run out of memory. If you revover the user can continue his work.